# How to use for-each in XQuery in OSB?

Tags: osb

Hi I want to select all from table to another table through Oracle service bus so that I am using X Query for transformation but it is transfer only one row so i need for-each function for all record but i do not how to use for-each? 
  please provide me methods to use for-each in X Query?

Answer (score 0):

The graphical XQuery editor might help. See samples here:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/dev.1111/e15866/examples.htm#OSBDV749

(esp Example 7-6)